# Exact one form on non-simply-connected manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Let $M$ be a smooth $n-$dimensional manifold and $\alpha\in\Lambda^1(M)$ a smooth $1-$form. Let $N\subset M$ be an embedded submanifold where $\alpha|_N=0$. If $d\alpha=0$ on the whole $M$, can I say that $\alpha$ is exact? $M$ is not simply-connected so this is not a trivial fact in principle since by Poincaré theorem I can just say it $\alpha$ is locally exact.

My idea is to work with the immersion map $I:N\rightarrow M$ so that the pull-back of $\alpha$ vanishes: $I^*\alpha =0$. Then can I conclude by linearity of the pull-back or something similar?

Comment: Think of $M=S^1$ and $N$ a single point. Or, if you like, $M=T^2$, $N$ circle. Can you think of a closed, nonexact $\alpha$ which vanishes on $N$?

Comment: Well in $S^1$ is not true because all $1-$forms are closed, but since it is not simply connected not all the forms are exact. But in $T^2$ I can't find examples satisfying your requirement. All closed forms should be of the type $\alpha=f(x)dx+g(y)dy$ with both $f,g$ 1-periodic. But then I can't think of an example

Comment: Hint: Use $g=0$. Can you now think of a circle on which the form vanishes?

Comment: Ok so I can consider the same $1-$form that I've taken for $S^1$, right? This means that in general what I have written in the question is false, did I interpret correctly your suggestions?

Comment: Yes; and yes, it is quite false.

Comment: Ok so probably in the paper where I've read it the reason behind this fact is peculiar of the situation, thanks